# c++ derived classes, one is the argument of the other

Tags: c++

I have a problem with two derived classes. I need that one receive the other as argument, but my code doesn't work (I semplified it to be more clear).

class:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> class A;
template <typename T> class B;
template <typename T> class C;

template <typename T> class A{

protected:

T **m;

void allocate_mem(T ***ptr){
    *ptr = new T*[1];
    (*ptr)[0] = new T[1];
}

public:

A(){
    throw logic_error("Error!");
}

~A(){
    delete[] m[0];
    delete[] m;
}

T say_elem(){
    return m[0][0];
}

};

template <typename T> class B: public A<T>{

public:

B(int val){
    A<T>::allocate_mem(& this->m);
    A<T>::m[0][0] = val;
}

};

template <typename T> class C: public A<T>{

public:

C(double val){
    A<T>::allocate_mem(& this->m);
    A<T>::m[0][0] = 1;
}

void renew(const B<T> &b){
    if(A<T>::b.say_elem() > 0){
        A<T>::m[0][0] = 1000;
    }
}

};
```

main:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "class.cpp"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char **argv){

B <int> bbb(4);

C <double> ccc(5);

ccc.renew(bbb);

//no matching function for call to 'C<double>::renew(B<int>&)'

return 0;

}
```

the error is indicated above, what i need to do?

Comment: You need to mark A::say_elem() const, if you want to use renew() with a const reference to B and then call say_elem().

Comment: I don't understand where I have to use A::say_elem() const...

Comment: `void renew(const B<T> &b) { b.say_elem(); }` will not compile because you can't call non-const methods of the const object b. You have to write `T say_elem() const {...}` in the definition of class A.

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: I wrote in A: T say_elem() const {
  return m[0][0];
       }

Comment: and in C: void renew(B<T> &b){
  if(A<T>::b.say_elem() > 0){
   A<T>::m[0][0] = 1000;
  }
 } but doesn't work

Comment: skip `A<T>::` in front of `b.say_elem()`. `b` is not a member or method. If you really like it `b.A<T>::say_elem()` is the correct usage.

Comment: always the same error, and it doesn't compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I combined Jefffrey's correct answer with my note from the comments to give a complete compiling and running code (which will throw logic_error("Error!") by the way, but this is off-topic).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdexcept>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> class A;
template <typename T> class B;
template <typename T> class C;

template <typename T> class A{
protected:

    T **m;

    void allocate_mem(T ***ptr){
        *ptr = new T*[1];
        (*ptr)[0] = new T[1];
    }

public:

    A(){
        throw logic_error("Error!"); // remove this line for expected behavior
    }

    ~A(){
        delete[] m[0];
        delete[] m;
    }

    T say_elem() const {
        return m[0][0];
    }

};

template <typename T> class B: public A<T>{
public:

    B(int val){
        A<T>::allocate_mem(& this->m);
        A<T>::m[0][0] = val;
    }
};

template <typename T> class C: public A<T>{
public:

    C(double val){
        A<T>::allocate_mem(& this->m);
        A<T>::m[0][0] = 1;
    }

    template <typename U>
    void renew(const B<U> &b){
        if(b.A<U>::say_elem() > 0){
            A<T>::m[0][0] = 1000;
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    B <int> bbb(4);
    C <double> ccc(5);

    ccc.renew(bbb);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call `C<T>::renew(const B<T> &)` with the wrong argument. What `renew` is expecting (in the call to the instance `C<double>`) is `const B<double>&`, not `const B<int>&`. They are two completely different classes. If you want to allow a `B` class with a different template parameter, templatize the function:

```
template<class U>
void renew(const B<U> &b) {
    if(b.say_elem() > 0){
        m[0][0] = 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: this give me other errors: 'b' is not a member of 'A<int>', 'int** A<int>::m' is protected, invalid use of non-static data member 'A<int>::m'